# Bootstrap Collapse with ACF Repeater?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, advanced-custom-fields

Just wondering if anyone could help me with my code please?

I've setup an ACF Repeater for the Bootstrap Collapse, which displays, but when I click the titles they don't collapse to show the content.

```
<?php if( have_rows('accordion') ): ?>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
<?php $i = 0; ; while ( have_rows('accordion') ) : the_row(); $i++; $tCount = $i; ?>

<div class="card">
<div class="card-header" id="heading<?php echo $tCount; ?>">
<button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse<?php echo $tCount; ?>" data-target="#collapse<?php echo $tCount; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse<?php echo $tCount; ?>"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></button>
</div><!--End Card Header-->
</div><!--End Card-->

<div id="collapse<?php echo $tCount; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $tCount; ?>" data-parent="#accordionExample">
<div class="card-body">
Text
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!--End Accordian-->
<?php else : endif; ?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, turned out I was echo'ing some PHP in the wrong area. If anybody needs the code, here it is:

```
<?php if( have_rows('accordion') ): ?>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
<?php $i = 0; ; while ( have_rows('accordion') ) : the_row(); $i++; $tCount = $i; ?>
<?php 
$field_accordion = get_sub_field_object('accordion_background_colour');
$value_accordion = $field_accordion['value'];
$label_accordion = $field_accordion['choices'][ $value_accordion ];
?>

<div class="card accordion-<?php echo $value_accordion; ?>-background">
<div class="card-header" id="heading<?php echo $tCount; ?>">
<button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?php echo $tCount; ?>" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse<?php echo $tCount; ?>">
<h4><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?> <i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
</button>
</div><!--End Card Header-->
</div><!--End Card-->

<div id="collapse<?php echo $tCount; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $tCount; ?>" data-parent="#accordion">
<div class="card-body">
Text
</div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!--End Accordian-->
<?php else : endif; ?>
```